# Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - Nativescript

Tags: android, angular, ssl, openssl, nativescript

I'm working on my first app and am codesharing (web-android). For the API I created a CAroot to use SSL and I put the CA.pem in the trusties CA(my pc). It is working correctly (https://10.0.02/6000)

In the 'api-rest' I put two files, `api.crt` and `api.key`. But I haven't found docs about doing something similar in `nativescript android` code. I get the follow error when I tried requesting over `https`:

```
> zoneAwareStack": "Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshake... LOG from device
> : "originalStack": "Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
> certification path not found.\n    at new ZoneAwareError
> (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:1298:31)\n
> at onRequestComplete
> (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/http/http-request/http-request.js:54:30)\n    at Object.onComplete
> (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/http/http-request/http-request.js:43:7)",
```

## What I tried

- Put the CAroot.pem in the Android 9.0.
- Modify `AndroidManifest.xml` and add `network_security_config.xml`

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        
        //ADDED
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        >
        ........
```

**network_security_config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
    
    <!-- ###.....THIS IS NEW.... but still not working -->
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

#### Additional info.

- I use `tns preview` and nativescript playground to develop the app.

### EDIT

I put the certificate and created these folders

[image]

But it is still not working. I don't know if this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: The documentation on this regard can be found in [Official Android Site](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config). Where have you placed your certificates in your project?

Comment: That's the problem. Im really new in Android, so nativescript is my easy way out to create and app so I dont know where I need to put my certificates... I will check that documentation.

Comment: You have to put it inside `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/raw/...`

Comment: I cant find `src/main/res/raw/`, I need to create them?

Comment: Yes, create if doesn't exist.

Comment: I solved. The real problems was that I use `tns preview`. That comand ignore changes in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Whit `tns run android` I have no problems. But a have new error.

Comment: That's whole purpose of preview, to run apps without building locally. For building app you use tns run.